# Create Sprint Burndown chart cross-org from Azure DevOps in Power BI

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I have the query below to construct Sprint Burndown cross-org in Azure DevOps. It works fine and smooth.

```
OData.Feed ("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/" & organization & "/" & projectName & "/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItemSnapshot?"
        &"$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'User Story'  and StateCategory ne 'Completed' and DateValue ge Iteration/StartDate and DateValue le Iteration/EndDate and Iteration/StartDate ge 2020-01-01Z)"
        &"/groupby( "
            &"(DateValue,State,WorkItemType,Area/AreaPath,Iteration/IterationPath,Iteration/StartDate,Iteration/EndDate), "
            &"aggregate($count as Count, StoryPoints with sum as TotalStoryPoints) "
        &") ",
    [#"Authorization" = "Basic " & apiKey]
    , [Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4])
```

However, I wanted to query the Teams under each of the project as well but it is not as straightforward as adding `Teams/TeamName` in the `groupby` section compared to Iteration and Area.

Below is my attempt that fails:

```
OData.Feed ("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/" & organization & "/" & projectName & "/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItemSnapshot?"
        &"$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'User Story'  and StateCategory ne 'Completed' and DateValue ge Iteration/StartDate and DateValue le Iteration/EndDate and Iteration/StartDate ge 2020-01-01Z)"
        &"/groupby( "
            &"(DateValue,State,WorkItemType,Teams/TeamName,Area/AreaPath,Iteration/IterationPath,Iteration/StartDate,Iteration/EndDate), "
            &"aggregate($count as Count, StoryPoints with sum as TotalStoryPoints) "
        &") ",
    [#"Authorization" = "Basic " & apiKey]
    , [Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4])
```

Comment: I have tried using `$expand` but it loads rather slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the more effective way is to use another OData endpoint `WorkItemBoardSnapshot` where I can do server side `groupby` which is far more efficient than doing it in Power BI.

Here is some reference:

```
OData.Feed ("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/" & organization & "/" & projectName &"/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItemBoardSnapshot?"
        &"$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'User Story'  and StateCategory ne 'Completed' and DateValue ge Iteration/StartDate and DateValue le Iteration/EndDate and Iteration/StartDate ge 2020-01-01Z)"
        &"/groupby("
            &"(DateValue,WorkItemType,Team/TeamName,Iteration/IterationPath,Iteration/StartDate,Iteration/EndDate),"
            &"aggregate($count as Count, StoryPoints with sum as TotalStoryPoints)"
        &")",
    [#"Authorization" = "Basic " & apiKey]
    , [Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4])
```

The diff is changing `WorkItemSnapshot` into `WorkItemBoardSnapshot` and notice that board snapshot is using `Team` instead of `Teams`.

Comment: Hi rick,
Thanks for your sharing, you could accept your answer. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution.

Comment: Hi Dharman, i tried using the same :**WorkItemBoardSnapshot** table and my objective was to filter and bring all workitems trending by Srint End of Date, however, everytime i try: `OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{proyect}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItemSnapshot?"
    &"$apply=filter(DateValue eq Iteration/StartDate)"
        ,
    null
    , [Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4])` it always throws a "empty table" result.  Do you know by chance what am i missing?